# ActiveRecord callback or MySql trigger?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, triggers

Lets say we have two models:

```ruby
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :statistics
end

class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :messages
end
```

The `Message` has `:state` attribute and it has to be updated based on `Statistic` counts (i.g. delivered_at, read_at). Meaning once the message was delivered to every user in the group the state has to be updated accordingly.
The `Statistics` timestamps updated in a sidekiq jobs with a query that does not invoke the callback (update_all) so I can't hook into 'after_update' callback of the Statistics and update the `Message.state`.
I've tried to do it using MySql after update trigger on Statistics table but had no luck because the query that invokes the trigger has the destination table (messages) in join.
Please advise.
Hope I was clear enough.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At first, it doesn't seem good that MySQL trigger is not working. This is the least expected behavior, because triggers are something that are native to the MySQL database, and they should work as and when you update your table, though be it by Rails, or by a query, or by any other entity. You should look at your trigger's code and debug it to find out why it is not working.

Alternatively, sidekiq jobs have `after_perform`, which is called when a job has done performing its work. You can write your code there. But still this doesn't guarantee that your job was successful or failed. So you need to take care of it.

Comment: Thanks! I think that sidekiq callbacks are in pro version only.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the JOIN in the query that invoked the trigger was unnecessary. Removed the JOIN and the trigger worked as expected.